# Error creating email template for custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, email-templates

I tried to create an email template in my custome module.In admin panel i got below error

> Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Ayakil_Muja_Helper_Data' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mage19\app\Mage.php on line 547

How I tried is below.

```
<config>
<modules>
    <ayakil_muja>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ayakil_muja>
</modules>
<global>
    <template>
        <email>
            <ayakilmuja_email_template1 module="muja">
                <label>ActiveCodeline custom email module</label>
                <file>ayakil_muja_custom_email1.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </ayakilmuja_email_template1>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
</config>
```

Created the template file `ayakil_muja_custom_email1.html` in `app\locale\en_US\template\email`

My data.php file in the module Helper folder is like below

```
<?php
class Ayakil_Muja_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

If I remove `module="muja"` part in `config.xml` the error is not coming.
What is this **module** here in `<template>` section?

Since I am creating a new module, Why I am getting errors from `Mage`?
Can any one help me to fix this error and create the email template or suggest me a good practice way to create the email template for custom module.

Comment: Can you please post full code of config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `helpers` in your `global` node like below, just add below helper node in your global node if you have write `module="ayakil_muja"` then it will search for helper class but in your `config.xml` definition, it will not find any  `ayakil_muja` helper that is why you got this error.

```
<global>
   <helpers>
    <muja>
        <class>Ayakil_Muja_Helper</class>
    </muja>
   </helpers>
   <template>
    <email>
        <ayakilmuja_email_template1 module="ayakil_muja">
            <label>ActiveCodeline custom email module</label>
            <file>ayakil_muja_custom_email1.html</file>
            <type>html</type>
        </ayakilmuja_email_template1>
    </email>
   </template>

</global>
```

Comment: thank you, i checked based on your answer.i want to add only <muja> instead of <ayakil_muja>

Answer (score 0):

You have to write you module name like this

```
<Ayakil_Muja>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
</Ayakil_Muja>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, this is not working